# Python numpy found in cmd line but not in script

Tags: python, numpy, terminal, scripting, pythonpath

When I launch python from the command line and import numpy it works fine. When I run the same code as a script it fails. This is on a centos box under corporate IT management (nothing I can install myself) I'm probably just missing something in my .cshrc, but what ??

**From cmd line:**

```
% python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Oct  7 2016, 09:54:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import argparse
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>>
```

**Same as script:**

```
#! /usr/bin/python 

import os.path
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
```

**Gives following error:**

```
% ./inter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./inter.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You may be accidentally referring to a different Python installation. Try modifying this line `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: Use 'python inter.py' to launch. In this way, you even don't need to set it executable.

Comment: @liliscent: that's true, but it's not programmable. How would the OP be able to use that in a more general case to automate some task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may be accidentally referring to a different Python installation.**

Try modifying this line `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python`. That is, it's likely that the Python your script is referring to is different than the one that's in your `$PATH`. You can confirm this by using comparing the script's Python (`/usr/bin/python`) against the result of this command: `which python`.

**In this case we use `env` to ensure that the Python interpreter used by the script is the one accessible in your `$PATH`.**